# Array filtering with multiple(or not) items

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter a array, passing throught the filter another array.

```
filterArray = [{BEERSERV-01,BEERSERV-02,BEERSERV-03}]


itemArray = [{
product1:{
equipamento: "BEERSERV-01"
id_pdv: "18225301000189"
item_venda: "OATMEAL STOUT - Mark The Shadow"
},
product2:{
equipamento: "BEERSERV-02"
id_pdv: "18225301000189"
item_venda: "IPA - Hector 5 Rounds"
},
product3:{
equipamento: "BEERSERV-03"
id_pdv: "20138940000159"
item_venda: "IPA - Hector 5 Rounds"
}

}
```

Those values will be selected in the SELECT of the printscreen below, each place had one of the values above, and at each select, i push thens to the filterArray.
For each select i do, a need a return of a new list with the selected value, but when the filterArray got more than 1 value, never return a value.

```
 public async gerarListaPDV(){
    let filtered = []
    this.filterarr = []
    console.log(this.filterarr.length)
    for(var x in this.pdvs_selecionados){
      for(var y in this.pdvs_selecionados[x].equipamentos){
        this.filterarr.push(this.pdvs_selecionados[x].equipamentos[y].nome_equipamento)
      }
    }
   
    this.lista_vendas_filtrada.filter((obj)=>{
           if(this.filterarr.includes(obj.equipamento)){
             console.log(this.filterarr)
             filtered.push(obj)
           }
    })
    this.exibir_por_pdv = filtered

    console.log(this.filterarr)
    if(this.filterarr.length >= 1){
      this.lista_vendas_filtrada = this.exibir_por_pdv 
    }
    else{
      this.lista_vendas_filtrada = this.lista_vendas_constante
    }
    this.carregarRelatorioTotal(true)
  
  }
```

[Filtering example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiAhM.png)

Answer (score 0):

your problem statement is hard to understand. I don't know what your issue is, but based on your *code*, there's an issue:

you're calling `filter` on `this.lista_vendas_filtrada`, but you're not returning anything in the callback.
Please take a look at what `filter` method does - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`filter` callback should return `true`if you want to keep the value in the new array that it returns, or `false` if you want to remove it *from the new array it returns*. `filter` does not modify the array it's called on.

Hope this helps. If you need more concrete answer, please edit your question to be [minimal reproduceable example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20reproducible,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.), write code in English, and format your question so it's not all in one unformatted paragraph.

Comment: I edited the question, i think now its more clearly